# Como puedo poner un rango de numeros para compararlos con un if

Tags: javascript

Quiero poner un rango de numeros para que se pueda hacer un if, quiero que se compare de 20 hasta el 25 pero con el if si lo pongo resultado < 25 se va hasta el 0:

```
function sumar() {
  var peso = parseFloat(document.getElementById("peso").value);
  var altura = parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);

  if (isNaN(peso) || isNaN(altura)) {
    document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "Ingresa un valor numérico para peso y altura.";
    return;
  }

  var resultado = Math.round(peso / (altura ** 2));
  document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "Su IMC es: " + resultado;

  /*DILE AL ALEX QUE TE PASE LA TABLA DE OBEESIDAD PARA HACER LOS DATOS*/
  if (resultado => 20 && resultado <= 25) {
    swal("Tienes una IMC de: " + resultado + ", estas normal, sigue cuidandote");
  }
}
```

Comment: el if se ve bien, tienes problemas con algún valor en específico?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x Si, si pongo un valor elevado para calcular el imc digamos arriba de 25 igual me da la alerta

Comment: Hola, dado que en tu código intervienen más valores, pon un ejemplo mínimo y verificable donde se vea el problema que indicas en la pregunta. Verifica el estado de cada valor, puede que ahí esté el problema.

Comment: En JavaScript no existe el operador `=>`, debería ser en su lugar `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un fallo en la multiplicación el cual te devuelve un 0 en tu código...

```
function sumar() {
  var peso = parseFloat(document.getElementById("peso").value);
  var altura = parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);

  if (isNaN(peso) || isNaN(altura)) {
    document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "Ingresa un valor numérico para peso y altura.";
    return;
  }
  /* Aquí tienes tu fallo en tu multiplicación con 2 operadores en vez de 1 */
  var resultado = Math.round(peso / (altura * 2));
  document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "Su IMC es: " + resultado;

  /*DILE AL ALEX QUE TE PASE LA TABLA DE OBEESIDAD PARA HACER LOS DATOS*/
  if (resultado >= 20 && resultado <= 25) {
    swal("Tienes una IMC de: " + resultado + ", estas normal, sigue cuidandote");
  }
}
```

Comment: Vendría mejor también mencionar sobre la *inexistencia* del operador `=>` ?)...

Comment: No me habia dado cuenta de ese fallo... Gracias.